# What music is playing in season 3 episode 2, 10 minutes into the episode?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

It's around the time when they are tasked with going through the forest and start showing of their quirks, starting with Shouji and Jirou saying "where the beasts are."

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about that scene at 09:40

The OST is : **Combat Training**  (it comes from Season 1)

Here is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oa9mT_sPkQA